# What is the standard Windows service timeout?

Tags: service, timeout

While starting or restarting a Windows service the service might time out, for example if you're starting is programmatically.

In my current script the timeout is set to 30 sec. and that applies to multiple services trough single variable, however on few occasions I noticed this timeout is hit and a service is not configured, it times out.

I don't want to set a timeout that is too high because this would slow down expecting a service that might otherwise not start no matter how big the timeout is, which results in bad user experience due to wait time.

So my question is what is the standard timeout for any Windows service?

How much timeout is acceptable or how much timeout should be set.

My goal here is that, if a service times out on standard timeout then I may conclude there is computer misconfiguration rather than too low timeout.

"Standard service timeout" could also be called "universally acceptable" or "normal"

Comment: There is a maximum amount of time Windows will wait for services to exit before terminating the service.  `WaitToKillServiceTimeout`. The default is 20 seconds.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/1b60cfe3-21de-7093-5530-147826f24445 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/waittokillservicetimeout-registry-value-does-not-work-in-windows-7-or-in-windows-server-2008-r2-55dfc381-f1b6-46ce-7945-0fd78f1090c5

Comment: Thanks, the resolution steps on this link say to change default value from 20sec to 60sec to resolve a problem. however this is for specific service, no mention that it applies to all services in general.